# Image gallery system with search engine using php

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to make an image gallery system with keywords. 
Each image has a `.php` file with a few variables:

```
    $keywords = 'Keywords that describe the image';
    $src = 'directory path leading to the image';
    $other = 'any specific remarks about the image';
```

the files of each image are stored in a directory called `imageinfo`. 
How can I get all the images listed in the files in the directory `imageinfo` to display in one `.php`file? They all have the same variable names. Can I make a search engine system to search the files?
This is very hard to explain, and I understand if you don't understand - feel free to grab a diet coke and come and write your problems in the comments!

Comment: Checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php for getting the directory contents. In general break down your problem into bits and search for a way to solve each bit and only post a question here if you have actually tried things and are genuinely stuck.

Comment: Instead of inventing something not as good and not as fast, why don't you use a database? Something like `MySQL` is super easy to use and cover all your requirements. I suggest you to grab a diet coke yourself, install `MySQL` and come back here if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(you have to fille the right imageinfo folder in)

```
<?php

// Folder with all the Info PHP files
$infodir = __DIR__ .'/imageinfo/';
// read Folder contens
$files = scandir( $infodir );
// Array to store all image infos
$allimages = array();
// loop, file for file
foreach ($files  as $file) {
    // . and .. are in the array of files, but we don't need them
    if( $file != '..' && $file != '.' ){

        //path to actual Image Info file
        $thisfile = $infodir.'/'.$file;
        //Check if file exists
        if( is_file( $thisfile ) ){
            //parse file
            include( $thisfile );

            //add vars to Array
            $allimages[] = array(
                'keywords' => $keywords,
                'src' => $src,
                'other '=> $other
            );
        }

    }
}

//Output Data of all files
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $allimages );
echo '<pre>';


//show images in browser
foreach ($allimages as $image ) {
    echo '<div class="img">';
    echo '<img src="'.$image['src'].'" title="" alt="" >';
    echo '<br />';
    echo $image['keywords'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $image['other'];
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```